# Добавление элементов в HashMap

Tags: java

Как реализовать добавление элементов в HashMap, чтобы в итоге получилось:

> {id1=cat, id2=pig, id3=parrot}

Код:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> map;
public static String id[] = new String[]{"id1", "id2", "id3"};
public static String name[] = new String[]{"cat", "pig", "parrot"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
}

public static void onId(){
    String ids = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < id.length; i++){
        ids = id[i];
        ...
    }
}

public static void onName(){
    String names = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
        names = name[i];
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна функция put

```
map.put(id[i], name[i]);
```

В функциях onName() и onId() будет происходить не то, что Вы ожидаете, так как переменные name и id повторяют названия глобальных массивов.

Comment: моя ошибка с именами. исправляю. но все же не много не понял ответа. мне необходимо, чтобы в первом методе заполнялись id, а во втором - уже к сохраненным данным, еще и прибавлялись name.

Comment: Java не предоставляет такого поведения HashMap. Вы можете написать надстройку над HashMap. Например так: собирать ключи и значения в два ArrayList'а и при необходимости заносить их в HashMap.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения.

Comment: Непонятно зачем все это. Но если уж очень сильно хочется, то на первом проходе вы можете в качестве значения положить null.